# How do I make a button in Swift to execute a line of HTML code?

Tags: swift, macos

I am working on a small desktop app that will open websites on the click of a button. It's sort of a bookmark launcher in app form. I need to be able to connect a button in Swift to a single line of HTML code and have the button execute the code.

This is not an iOS app, it is macOS only. I am not looking to launch a UIWebView, I just need a single line of HTML executed.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I just need a single line of HTML executed. "  What line?  Your question sounds nothing but odd.  How would you tell your application which line to execute?

Comment: Since you didn't specify anything about the line of HTML you want to execute, I'm just going to go ahead and assume that the line is this: `<!-- Hello There -->`. Now then. To have your button execute this line of code, just... create the button. You don't even have to connect it to an action. Easy peasy!

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand what you mean by "execute html code"

if you have a link and want to open it you can do:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(url:"your url")
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace